# How to intercept a constructor

Tags: java, bytecode, byte-buddy

I want to intercept all methods who are annotated with @Inject. The following test shows that it works fine with methods but it does not with constructors. What am I missing?

I tried to add a custom method matcher and I noticed I was never given a MethodDescription corresponding to the constructor.

```
public class InterceptConstructorTest {

    @Test
    public void testConstructorInterception() {

        ByteBuddyAgent.install();

        new AgentBuilder.Default().type(nameStartsWith("test")).transform(new AgentBuilder.Transformer() {

            @Override
            public Builder<?> transform(Builder<?> builder, TypeDescription td) {

                return builder.method(isAnnotatedWith(Inject.class))
                        .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(MethodInterceptor.class).andThen(SuperMethodCall.INSTANCE));
            }
        }).installOnByteBuddyAgent();

        // Call constructor => NOT intercepted 
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass("a param");

        // Call method => intercepted
        myClass.aMethod("a param");
    }
}

class MyClass {

    @Inject
    public MyClass(String aParam) {
        System.out.println("constructor called");
    }

    @Inject
    public void aMethod(String aParam) {
        System.out.println("aMethod called");
    }
}

class MethodInterceptor {

    public static void intercept(@Origin Method method) {
        System.out.println("Intercepted: " + method.getName());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
constructor called
Intercepted: aMethod
aMethod called
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specify explicitly that you only want to intercept methods:

```
builder.method(isAnnotatedWith(Inject.class))
```

You can similarly do:

```
builder.constructor(isAnnotatedWith(Inject.class))
```

Or even:

```
builder.invokeable(isAnnotatedWith(Inject.class))
```

Here is the catch, however. Any constructor **must** call another constructor from within the constructor that is intercepted. In your case, this is already given by using `SuperMethodCall.INSTANCE` and your code will run. Be however careful that some constructs are not available for constructors, for example, you can not inject a `@This` reference before the super constructor is called. If appropriate, you would for example switch:

```
MethodDelegation.to(MethodInterceptor.class)
                .andThen(SuperMethodCall.INSTANCE)
```

to become

```
SuperMethodCall.INSTANCE
               .andThen(MethodDelegation.to(MethodInterceptor.class))
```

When using this ordering, the JVM does no longer complain if inject properties of the intercepted instance.

Finally, make sure that you offer an appropriate interception:

```
class MethodInterceptor {

    public static void intercept(@Origin Method method) {
        System.out.println("Intercepted: " + method.getName());
    }

    public static void intercept(@Origin Constructor<?> constructor) {
        System.out.println("Intercepted: " + constructor.getName());
    }
}
```

Otherwise, Byte Buddy cannot bind a `Constructor` reference to a `Method` and discards the method from binding (since 0.7.6, before, there is a bug where a verifier error is caused instead.) When using Java 8, you can also offer a single interceptor using the `Executable` type.

Comment: I tried both with "constructor" and "invokable" and I get the following exception (version 0.7.5): http://pastebin.com/peUnSdDw

Comment: You are using @Origin with a Method type where Constructor should be used. Byte Buddy should catch that, its a bug. You need to use Constructor as a type for that interceptor.

Comment: Oh right, thanks! Now I better understand the exception message. I had no idea that the reflection API made a distinction between constructors and methods. Having method/constructor/invokable on the builder makes more sense too.

Comment: Ill fix it and push a new version tomorrow morning.